# In a WiX Bundle, how can I supply a settings file for an ExePackage?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, burn

I am authoring a WiX bundle that installs several other pre-build packages, some are MSIs and some are EXEs.

One of the EXE packages requires a settings file to be supplied which I have to give the path to on the command line.

```
  <ExePackage Id="exePackage"
              Description="Executable Installer"
              PerMachine="yes"
              InstallCommand="-settings=TheConfigurationFile.txt"
              SourceFile="RedistributablePackages\TheInstaller.exe" >
```

How should I package `TheConfigurationFile.txt` so that the EXE installer can find it? It isn't clear to me how to do that as I can't seem to find any way to specify a file in connection with the ExePackage...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Payload element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/payload.html).

```
<Payload SourceFile="TheConfigurationFile.txt"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It's amazing how you can stare at the documentation for an hour and miss something like that!